# Problems in Java Hex Numbers

Tags: java, hex, sign

I will edit the question.

I shouldn't possibly get a negative number in L and R. but the final answer is negative for both of them.

here

```
    long sum = 0L;
    long delta = 0x9e3779b9L;
    long L=0x01234567;
    long R=0x89ABCDEF;
    long K0 = 0xA56BABCDL;
    long K1 = 0x00000000L;
    long K2 = 0xFFFFFFFFL;
    long K3 = 0xABCDEF01L;

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    sum = sum + delta;
    L = L + (((R << 4) + K0) ^ (R + sum) ^ ((R >> 5) + K1));
    R = R + (((L << 4) + K2) ^ (L + sum) ^ ((L >> 5) + K3));
    System.out.println(L + "   " + R);
}
```

Is there any way to use Hex data type in java and make my life easy???? Is there any Hex API which supports the shift operations and the XOR operations easily. This shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: It would be nice to have the starting values and the types for all those variables.

Comment: Sorry forgot those, reediting the problems

Comment: I kinda think the problem might be that the long is going out of range, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you  need to avoid overflow by shifting left, you  want to use a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead of a long to store your number.  BigInteger has methods to support `or`, as well as left and right shift operations, and since BigInteger has arbitrary precision, left shift won't overflow or switch the sign of the number.

Comment: the problem with Big Integer is that when i shift to left, I want the leftmost bit to be dropped. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may be able to use a BitSet, but you'll need to write your own methods for dropping the leftmost bit, "and", masking, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Append an `L` here

```
long delta = 0x9e3779b9L; // note final L
```

so that it becomes an [integer literal of type `long`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) Without the `L` (or `l`), the `int` value of the literal `0x9e3779b9` is taken which overflows into negative value and then that value is [widened to a `long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Comment: It still doesn't work in this statement

L = L + (((R << 4) + K0) ^ (R + sum) ^ ((R >> 5) + K1));

Here L and R are two Hex values. The shifting makes them negative

Comment: @user2782324 Can you edit your question with the full code? I don't want to make assumptions.

Comment: Enough left shifting (`<<`), will cause a number to be negative when the far-left bit becomes one, even if you are using long primitives.

Comment: @user2782324 I don't have time to go through all the `<<` shifts and `^` XORs, but as lreeder says, at some point the values will overflow.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this??

Comment: @user2782324 Yes, you can get treat Java integers as unsigned. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the unsigned right shift operator `>>>` instead of the normal right shift operator `>>`. Thus the sign bit will not be preserved but instead be shifted as well. This lets you treat the Java integer types as unsigned integers.